# Saving and loading numpy record as multi-part files

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

See the below code. When `np.save` is called the `numpy` record is saved as a single big file. I wanted to have `numpy` save it into small parts based on some specified chunk size and some auto file naming. Finally, the `np.load` should load it as `memmap` over all part files.

I am surprised as to why this is not available within numpy. I tried to search for it too. Am I missing something?

p.s.: `np.recarray` has no significance apart from accessing record columns as attributes.

```py
import numpy as np

_size = 10000
_x = np.empty(_size, dtype=np.float32)
_y = np.empty(_size, dtype=np.int32)

npy_rec = np.recarray((_size,), dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
npy_rec.x = _x
npy_rec.y = _y

np.save("npy_rec.npy", npy_rec)
npy_rec_ = np.load("npy_rec.npy", mmap_mode="r").view(np.recarray)

print(npy_rec)
print(npy_rec_)
```

Comment: From the `save/load` standpoint, there isn't any difference between a `recarray` and an array with a simple `dtype`.  `npy` file has information on the `dtype` and `shape`, and a copy of data buffer.  `load` does have a memmap mode, but it works with one file, where it can read the databuffer copy as though it were an in-memory buffer.  There's no chunking in-memory either, but you can read slices from either.

Comment: Just ignore the `np.recarray`. I am aware that `np.array` and `np.recarray` are the same. Sorry if it confuses the question. But what I want is to save and load multi-part numpy records i.e. chunking while saving on disk. Are you aware of any library that can do it?

Comment: `HDF5/h5py` has chunking, though it's internal to its file, not multi-file.

Comment: I can come up with chunking myself, but was checking first if there is something already available. I need to limit my file sizes to 200MB and hence want to break files while saving. Any help will be appreciated. `HDF5/h5py` is out of the question as it stores thing in one large file.

Comment: Why the limit on file sizes? There might be a better way of doing things.

Comment: I want to move data to a multi-GPU setup where each GPU will consume 200MB data. Having multiple file chunks will achieve parallel IO when moving data to multiple GPUs. I assume there can be more reasons to do that kind of thing so it would be better to focus on How rather than Why.